# Using Elementor, how can I wrap text around other elements?

Tags: wordpress, elementor

I'm looking for a way I can have the text in one column wrap around other elements to overflow into other columns. Is this possible?

Here's an image of the page to illustrate what I mean.

[image: A page with a heading and text in the left column, and an image in the right column.]

What I would like is for the text to extend its width to both columns after the image. The image is a known height and width.

If it's not possible using Elementor/Wordpress, advice on how to do it with HTML would also work.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

You don't want to use columns. You want to use css float property.

Edit: I am not sure with elementor specifically, but most builders and the built-in WYSIWYG allow to to set float on images without having to use CSS yourself. But if you need to the property is:

```
.specific-image {
  float: right;
}
```

Note that this could cause some weird alignment with the image and the title text. Might need to also adjust the margin on the image.